# Is there a possible Control for this?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently using net beans with Java to work on a senior project. Essentially the program is going to create word search puzzles.

While I'm still a few weeks from needing a solution, I'm having difficulty thinking of a possible control that could display a word search puzzle (not to be mistaken for a crossword puzzle).

Comment: More details would be helpful here.  What do you mean by control?  Is the user going to input the words/dimensions of the crossword puzzle?  Should it be an interactive game or should it just print static text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought would be to have a grid of subclassed JPanels stored in another subclass of JPanel [as a 2D array, or something].
You could then attach MouseListeners to the grid cell JPanels if you need to detect if they've been clicked on, or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Might give you an idea

[brainjar - Wordsearch](http://www.brainjar.com/java/games/wordsearch/) (source at bottom of page)

What do you mean by control? Maybe something like a JTable + Custom ListSelectionModel